# Blender 3.0 Geometry Nodes: density from texture?

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes

I would like to grow grass in the joints of pavement, so for this I connect an image texture to the density of a distribute points node, with color ramp and multiply for finetuning. Whatever I try, the density doesn't seem to get influenced by the texture.

[image: density from texture (doesn't get this to work)]

Connecting the texture to the instance scale works as expected, I just cannot get the density to work. What am I overlooking here? Any help is deerly appreciated.

[image: instance scale from texture (works as expected)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you subdivide your mesh? This node setup works for me:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... looks like density is defined per face, which should be documented, to say the least.

Comment: This seems like a reason to carry on using particles in some circumstancdes - until this is fixed at least